# How to set Nginx pattern matching correctly?

Tags: nginx

I have a beta server running on port 8002 and a prod server on port 8001

I would like the beta server to serve urls like beta.xxx.com, fr.beta.xxx.com, en.beta.xxx.com and so on, while the prod server is meant to serve xxx.com, fr.xxx.com, en.xxx.com

Here is my nginx config :

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  ~.* beta.xxx.com$;
  access_log   logs/xxx_beta.access.log  main;
  root         html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8002;
  }
}


server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  ~.* xxx.com$;
  access_log   logs/xxx.access.log  main;
  root         html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8001;
  }
}
```

However, all the traffic goes to the beta server.

I have tried various patterns : `^-.*` instead of `~`, end with a `$` or not, ... none worked. I didn't forgot to `service nginx reload` in between config changes. Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the leading regex stuff here -- server pattern matching don't generally use that. I would run with:

```
# qa
server {
   server_name .beta.example.com;
}

# prod
server {
   server_name .example.com;
}
```

That should make everything looking for anything in the beta.example.com to hit the QA site and anything else should hit the main site.